# Thevenin Equivalence Problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, automotive, thevenin, homework

So I have this question that I'm struggling to understand and solve, it goes like this:

**I want to determine the Thevenin equivalent of my car battery. You measure a voltage of 12.2V across the battery while it supplies a current of 1A. When I turn the headlights on, the load current increases to 8A and the voltage drops to 11.88V. What would be the Thevenin equivalent voltage and resistance?**

How would I go about solving this? I struggle to imagine it being a linear circuit.

Comment: The Thevenin voltage is measured without load current flowing.

Comment: @Hendrik: Ok let's see how far we can get: Why is the voltage on the battery dropping from 12.2V to 11.88V?

Comment: @Oldfart I would think it is because of the headlights acting as a load on the circuit, but I can't be sure. This was a Theoretical question given to us by our lecturer so I'm not sure if we are supposed to look at it practically or simply do the maths.

Comment: Thévenin models a circuit (loaded or not by the way) linearized at a given operating point. It is perfectly valid to determine the model by measuring two voltage drops at two different output currents providing the circuit remains linear between the two loading conditions. Actually if the two output currents are very close to each other, you differentiate the transfer characteristic at the given operating point and the obtained slope is the small-signal resistance you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theravin equivilent would be

12.2V - 11.88V (the voltage across the resistance) = 0.32V,

0.32V / 7A (the change in current that made that voltage) = 45.7 milliohms

Now we have the resistance, just need to reverse out the source voltage

1A * 0.0457 = 0.0457V,

So 12.257V with a resistance of 45.7 milliohm,

Comment: Please don't provide homework solutions unless the OP has shown a significant amount of effort and shown all of their work. We don't want this to become a homework solution service.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Im sorry for having to bring my homework question to this site, but after hours of struggling and not getting anywhere I thought someone on this site could explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw circuits of both situations it will help. So pardon my drawings as I’m answering this on my phone.

Since the info doesn’t state the open circuit voltage but rather voltage and current for two scenarios, we have to derive the battery internal resistance from this data.

Looking at the drawing shown below, we can use ohms law with the fact that current in one scenario is eight times the other current in other scenario. Using algebra we can cancel out R variable and solve for Vs. Then using ohms law we can find R with known Vs. I’ll leave it to you to solve this.

[image]